Output Classification prediction in KPConv
I am working with the classification model from KPConv github. For the classification model(Modelnet40), i wrote some code to save the output/predicton from the model as txt file along with the coordinate of the lidar point cloud. However this is not working. It just keeps running and doesnot complete the task even when i reduce the number of test files.
def predict(self, net, test_loader, output_file, config):
    softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(1)

    nc_tot = test_loader.dataset.num_classes

    nc_model = config.num_classes

    self.test_probs= np.zeros((test_loader.dataset.num_models, nc_model))
    self.test_counts = np.zeros((test_loader.dataset.num_models, nc_model))

    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        while np.min(self.test_counts) < 5:
            probs = []
            targets = []
            obj_inds = []

            for batch in test_loader:
                if "cuda" in self.device.type:
                    batch.to(self.device)

                outputs = net(batch, config)
                probs_batch = softmax(outputs).cpu().detach().numpy()
                probs += [probs_batch]
                targets +=[batch.labels.cpu().numpy()]
                obj_inds += [batch.model_inds.cpu().numpy()]

                for i, inds  in enumerate(batch.model_inds.cpu().numpy()):
                    prediction = np.argmax(probs_batch[i])
                    f.write(f'{inds} {prediction}\n')

    print("prediction save")

